# Breezejs without c# code

Tags: c#, javascript, entity-framework, breeze

*I have just started learning for **breezejs** !*

I have two doubts

**1) Is the breezejs doing any changes directly on database or need any c# codes?**

> If we write any **savechanges**  query in breezejs, then the values are update to database?
>
> if yes, then we need or not need Ajax call and write any codes in C# ?

---

**2) Can we write CRUD Operations in GUI side  using breezejs without using c#  code?**

Answer (score 1):

Breeze offers several options for communicating with a server. Out of the box we offer backends in both .NET and Node.  Examples of each are available in the breeze zips here: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download.   Breeze also offers the ability to talk to an arbitrary backend that does NOT implement a breeze compatible server.  See the 'edmunds' example in the zip mentioned above.

### Current Breeze Server impls

- .NET - WebApi 2

  - Entity framework ( with any EF supported SQL DB)
  - NHibernate       ( with any NH supported SQL DB)
  - No database or custom implementation
- Node - Express

  - MongoDB
- Java  ( not yet complete but in progress )
- Ruby  ( not yet complete but in progress)